# Paypal Pro Checkout- different links created for contribution pages and webforms

Tags: civicontribute, webform-civicrm, payment-processor, contribution-page, paypal

We have a site with Paypal pro configured as default payment processor.

One membership contribution page is linked to a webform (gathers additional contact data). Credit Cards details entered directly into the webform, are processed without a problem.

If a user opts to checkout via paypal the payment fails. The form attempts to connect to paypal.com but the error message

> *api_username*
>   Your purchase couldn't be completed
>   Error Message
>
> We cannot process this transaction because there is a problem with the PayPal email address supplied by the seller. Please contact the seller to resolve the problem. If this payment is for an eBay listing, you can contact the seller via the "Ask Seller a Question" link on the listing page. When you have the correct email address, payment can be made at www.paypal.com.

Comes up.

If I amend the payment processor settings in Civi and swap the api username, for the related account username, the paypal link works. payments can be processed.

Unfortunately other contribution pages (public donation pages) then fail to process payments.

After trial and error, we've identified that if you choose the paypal checkout button directly from the contribution page. A link like this is generated

https://www.paypal.com//cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_express-checkout&token=EC-1154497557710463X#/checkout/login

If you follow the paypal checkout button from the webform the following link is generated

https://www.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_flow&SESSION=RfwxDcyRqYm82K4aVOuVoCtO0ABMP8r6OO95Oyvm14UqvsIuD_Av9c0ehSu&dispatch=50a222a57771920b6a3d7b606239e4d529b525e0b7e69bf0224adecfb0124e9b61f737ba21b081984719ecfa9a8ffe80733a1a700ced90ae

Does anyone know what may be causing two different links to be generated from the same underlying payment processor?

Is there any way of updating the webform so that the link to paypal comes out in the form
https://www.paypal.com//cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_express-checkout&token=EC-1154497557710463X#/checkout/login   ?

My brain has melted trying to explain this as simply as possible. If anything is not clear. Please ask for clarification.

Comment: I've now added the same paypal account as a new payment processor.

One processor  uses the api user name. the other uses the account username.

I've linked the webform to the payment processor using the account username, and left the contribution pages linked to the processor using the api username.

Will keep an eye on proceedings and see if this fixes things.